# Can you pick up Pete's Watch in Walking Dead - Season 2

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-two

As I was going through the house in the first episode, I noticed a watch (Pete's Watch) inside a drawer. I didn't bother looking closer to see if it gave me the option to pick it up.

Now, in Episode 2, I'm talking with Nick at the bench (after crossing the bridge) and he mentioned that he left the watch back at the cabin.

Was I able to pick that watch up at that point if I had of tried, and given it to him at this point.